# using table in list data region for repeat data in rdlc

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, dataset, rdlc

I use 2 table in a list data region for repeating data. I group data in list data region.
My dataset that used in table have 3 data table. I can't use of all data tables as data provider for report. When I open Expression window and click on Datasets, all datasets shown to me but all of their fields use of an aggregate function like sum.
How can I use all of data tables in my report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure but as far as i know list data can have only one datatable as datasource. This is why you can use only one of the 3 tables. The only way i know for such situation is combine if possible, the 3 tables as one.
Best Regards,
Iordan